# What is the explanation for the structure of foam?

Tags: fluid-statics, bubbles

When you look at any gas in liquid foam, you'll see a particular structure.[image: "foam at the surface of a cup of tea"]

You'll find that the structure consists of some bigger bubbles along with some smaller and smaller ones.
I would like to know the reason for this.
I don't find it obvious as I would assume the foam to be one big bubble or a collection of similar bubbles. Why this peculiar pattern?
A few ideas which may be involved in this may be

1. [Plateau's Law of minimum surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plateau%27s_laws)
2. Energy minimisation

I would love to have your thoughts about this

Answer (score 1):

We can't expect the bubble-production mechanism to be perfectly repeatable. (In fact, it [takes great engineering effort](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10404-008-0368-3) to produce uniform bubbles and droplets.)

More importantly, [coarsening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostwald_ripening) is an effect that imparts **non**uniformity—large bubbles/droplets/precipitates becoming larger and small elements becoming smaller—because smaller elements contain more surface area per unit volume and are thus less energetically favorable.

The equilibrium case is a single large region that forms through mass transport/coalescence.